# Get only JSON string as output without any html

Tags: asp.net, json

I am developing a webiste in ASP.NET. On one of the pages page named menu.aspx, with the help of a certain login, I am getting the output in this format

`foo({"1":"Jeff","2":"Mik","5":"Tom"});`

I am using this code to get the output on the JSON form.

```
outputText += Convert.ToString(k.GetValue(0));
            for (Int32 i = 1; i < k.Length; i++)
            {
                outputText += "," + Convert.ToString(k.GetValue(i));
            }
            //
            outputText += "}" +");";
            Response.Clear();
            Response.Write(outputText);
            Response.ContentType = "application/json";
```

However, I must get the output only in simple JSON on the page without any HTML.

For eg: Here's the screenshot showing the source of the output page. https://i.stack.imgur.com/faUtY.jpg

Notice that it has only the JSON string as the output.

And here's the screenshot showing the output page source (with HTML). https://i.stack.imgur.com/gIxzR.jpg  .This HTML is what I have to remove. How can do I do this?
The full code of menu.aspx.cs is putup here. http://pastebin.com/M14Srrgf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend switching to a web service, but for this try adding a response.end call after you write the string.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you might be interested in an ASHX Handler. Think of it as code-behind without the view. [Here](http://www.aspcode.net/Creating-an-ASHX-handler-in-ASPNET.aspx) is a good explanation.

Comment: Also, you might be interested in using a library to help out with writing JSON. Here is one that I use that works well with .NET: http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your JSON output HTTP call should be in a different request.  You could first load the HTML page and then from the HTML page make an AJAX call to your server to get the JSON by itself.